# Regular FancyBox 1.3.4 w/ Wordpress - Link

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox

when I search for this on google I just get a lot of wordpress plugin responses, so I'm asking here.

I have a wordpress.org blog. There's a link that, onclick, I would like to open up a fancybox w/ some content inside of it, actually a spotify embeded playlist w/ a header.

I've included all of the fancybox files and initialize, and no luck. Here is my code:

Initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("a#playlist_pop").fancybox({
                                'overlayShow'   : false,
                                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
                        });
                    });
                  </script>
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="spotify_header" style="padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10PX;text-align: center">CHECK US OUT ON <a id="playlist_pop" href="#playlist_data"><span>SPOTIFY</span></a>
                        <div style="display:none">
                            <div id="playlist_data">
                                <div id="Spotiplay">
                                    <h3>Artists We Love</h3><br/>
                                    <div id="playlist_pop_con"><iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:yalefox:playlist:3NCBHSkbl0jLZtUnNWkdPh" width="312" height="392" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div></div>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Incredible how something so easy can be made such a pain in wordpress..

I get this error message in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Does this mean it's not reading the fancybox js files?

Comment: Please install firebug on file fox and paste some error log here

Comment: a link to the site with the issue would be much helpful

Comment: There's not much else in the error log than what I posted that applies to this. The site isn't live so I can't post it either. Maybe there's a better solution using an iframe? I'm going to try it one more time but this time I'm going to put the fancybox files right into the root directory instead of their own folder..that worked for the carouFredSel app I'm using, which had the same error msg, but it was in an iframe. Not sure if that matters. I'll update either way!

Comment: If there's no method 'fancybox' then there's got to be an issue reading the fancybox JS. I'd check that you have all the right script loaded - and in the right order. jQuery first, then fancybox, then fancybox-pack, then any helpers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help. Not sure if it has anything to do with my client's blog configuration or just a lack of support for regular Fancybox 1.3.2 and wordpress.org, but I had to resort to the Lytebox wordpress plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lytebox/ -where you just include a rel="lyteframe" in the a tag..I restyled it to look just like a fancybox, so while not optimal or as robust as fancybox, it's not a bad alternative